# Non-serializable Matcher in Wicket Behavior

Tags: serialization, wicket, matcher, hamcrest

I was building a visibility behavior on Wicket that used Hamcrest `Matcher` (and some Lambdaj) to see if any of the given property models values match the given matcher and if so, then it would hide the component.

```
public class HiddenWhenValueMatchesBehavior<T> extends Behavior {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  Collection<IModel<T>> models;
  Matcher<T> matcher;

  public HiddenWhenValueMatchesBehavior(Matcher<T> matcher, IModel<T>... models) {
    this.models = Arrays.<IModel<T>> asList(models);
    this.matcher = matcher;
  }

  @Override
  public void onConfigure(Component component) {
    super.onConfigure(component);
    component.setVisible(!hasItem(matcher).matches(extract(models, on(IModel.class).getObject())));
  }
}
```

Only then I realized that Hamcrest Matchers are not serializable and according to their issue tracker they have no intention to ever be serializable.

Above is just an example, I could see several uses for passing `Matchers` to `Behavior`s and other Wicket stuff.

Any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the matcher in a model:

public HiddenWhenValueMatchesBehavior(IModel> matcher, IModel... models) {

Comment: BTW everything holding a reference to a model should detach it, this holds for your behavior too.

Answer (score 1):

Marking the Matcher as transient can help. But you need a way to have this dependency available after the behavior gets deserialized. @SpringBean can do that automatically if you are using Spring.

or

Wrap your component's model object into a LoadableDetachableModel, move your Matcher and matching logic into it, make the Matcher transient again. The load method can create instance of Matcher every time and load the model object.